# Failed to load settings. Temporarily using the Windows Terminal default settings

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

Okay so I have a script that goes like this:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}

$host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
cls

Write-Host -NoNewLine "Wcisnij DOWOLNY by rozpoczac";
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
Write-Host " "
Write-Host " "

$host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "White"

Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name 'Ethernet' -ComponentID 'ms_tcpip6'
$adapterV6 = Get-NetAdapterBinding -Name 'Ethernet' -ComponentID 'ms_tcpip6'

for($i=0;$i -le 5;$i++){
    Write-Host "*" -NoNewline
}

$hostname = hostname
$currentIP = (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null -and $_.IPEnabled -eq $true }).IPAddress[0]
$firstThreeOctets = $currentIP -replace '\.\d+$', ''

for($i=0;$i -le 5;$i++){
    Write-Host "*" -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
}

if ($hostname -like "*S1") {
    $desiredIP = "$firstThreeOctets.10"
} else {
    $number = $hostname -replace '[^0-9]', ''
    $desiredIP = "$firstThreeOctets.20$number"
}

for($i=0;$i -le 5;$i++){
    Write-Host "*" -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
}

$adapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null -and $_.IPEnabled -eq $true }
$adapter.EnableStatic($desiredIP, "255.255.255.0") | Out-Null

$dnsServers = "8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1"
$adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dnsServers) | Out-Null

for($i=0;$i -le 5;$i++){
    Write-Host "*" -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2
}

$gateway1 = "$firstThreeOctets.254"
$gateway2 = "$firstThreeOctets.253"
$gateways = @($gateway1, $gateway2)
$adapter.SetGateways($gateways) | Out-Null

for($i=0;$i -le 5;$i++){
    Write-Host "*" -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3
}

$username = $env:UserName
$gemini = $username.Substring(0, 6)

$host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
cls
Write-Host "         mgawron" -ForegroundColor DarkRed -NoNewline
Write-Host "; " -NoNewline
Write-Host "Banklek" -ForegroundColor Blue
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "          Apteka: " -NoNewline
if ($gemini -like "Gemini"){

    $indexNawias = [regex]::Match($username, "\(").Index
    $indexDo = $indexNawias - 6
    $miasto = $username.Substring(6, $indexDo)

    Write-Host "Gemini" -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host "          Miasto: " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$miasto" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}else{
    Write-Host "$username" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Write-Host " Nazwa komputera: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$hostname" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Oryginalny adres: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$currentIP" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "    Obecny adres: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$desiredIP" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "           Maska: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "255.255.255.0" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "         Brama 1: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$gateway1" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "         Brama 2: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$gateway2" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "            DNSy: " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$dnsServers" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "            IPV6: " -NoNewline
if ($adapterV6.Enabled){
    Write-Host "Wlaczone" -ForegroundColor Green
}else{
    Write-Host "Wylaczone" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
Read-Host
```

The script is intended to set the IP on new computers being setup in a pharmacy. It works fine on my PC, it works fine on PC's in the office, but as soon we get to the pharmacy and open the script:

> Failed to load settings
> Settings could not be loaded from file. Check for syntax errors, including trailing commas,
> *Line 1, Column 1
> Syntax error: value, object or array expected.
> Temporarily using the Windows Terminal default settings.

And then it closes and does nothing. The first line is just for if you right click the file to Run with PowerShell it automatically runs in admin. As I said: the script works, I tested it on THE SAME computer that went out into the pharmacy, but in the pharmacy it doesn't work. Anyone has a clue?

As I said: the script works, I tested it on THE SAME computer that went out into the pharmacy, but in the pharmacy it doesn't work. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Do you have IPV4 or IPV6?  ms_tcpip6

Comment: When you say "open the script" do you mean it errors even when you try to open the ps1 file in ISE?

Comment: the computers are setup before we leave the office. then we use the script at the pharmacy because we dont know the first three octets before we get there. both IPV4 and IPV6 is turned on before running the script. When i say open the script i mean that i right click "run with powershell" then it flashes the error message and disappears

Comment: PC is probably using IPV4 while pharmacy is Wi-Fi using IPV6.  Wi-Fi may be using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across PowerShell displaying this error message.  I don't believe that the problem is with your script at all.  As the error message suggest, **Failed to load settings**, which it would be useful if it provided a reference to the file.  Open the PowerShell Terminal and press **`Ctrl+,`** (control+comma) to open the settings.

[image: where to open the settings.json file]

At the bottom left, click the Open JSON file, which for me ended up being a binary file, full of **NUL** entries, which isn't JSON, hence the error.

Deleting the contents of the `%USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekybd8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json` (**NOTE:** The Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekybd8bbwe bit is possibly different per install/version) file fixes the problem.

Before:
[image: before deleting all the NUL characters]

After:
[image: after deleting all the NUL characters]

As I had the Terminal Window open, as soon as the NUL characters were removed, it immediately updated in VSCode.